# Benefits of async for Single-Threaded Application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am writing a WebAPI microservice and am wondering if there is benefit to using `async`. The service makes some calls to a SQL database through Entity Framework.

**Synchronous:**

```
using(var db = new Entities())
{
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault();
    user.IsActive = false;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Asynchronous:**

```
using(var db = new Entities())
{
    var user = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    user.IsActive = false;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Unlike some use cases of `async` I've seen, there is no processing done between kicking off the awaitable subtasks and the suspension that comes from the `await` (hence "single-threaded," though perhaps not literally).

*My question is*, from a resource standpoint, how is this really different from the synchronous alternative? Assuming it is asynchronous all the way through the controller, will the service scale better?

BONUS POINTS: What are the implications of doing some synchronous blocking in an otherwise asynchronous application (if a developer forgets to utilize an async method, for instance)?

Comment: What does "asynchrounous" mean?

Comment: Returning a Task instead of a result. "All the way through the controller" means that a task is never called with .Result or .Wait()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you read my [intro to async on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) article, especially the first half.

> My question is, from a resource standpoint, how is this really different from the synchronous alternative?

The synchronous version blocks a thread in your web server until the SQL query and update are all completed. The asynchronous version does not consume a thread in your web server while the SQL query and update are in progress. Fewer threads means that your web service can more easily do other things.

> Assuming it is asynchronous all the way through the controller, will the service scale better?

Your web service? Yes. Your service as a whole? It depends; specifically, it depends on how your backend scales. If it's just a single SQL server backend, then there's (probably) no point in scaling your web server because your SQL server is going to be your bottleneck. If it's a SQL cluster or Azure SQL, then (probably) using async would be beneficial to your system as a whole.

> BONUS POINTS: What are the implications of doing some synchronous blocking in an otherwise asynchronous application (if a developer forgets to utilize an async method, for instance)?

Then a thread is consumed for that operation. E.g., if the asynchronous version used `FirstOrDefaultAsync` with `SaveChanges` (not `SaveChangesAsync`), then the thread would be freed up during the query but be blocked during the save.